# Trying to print list of object names, just get memory address instead

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the code in question for the Person class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, email, yearRounder, symptomatic, tested):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.email = email
        self.yearRounder = yearRounder
        self.symptomatic = symptomatic
        self.tested = tested
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

I'm assigning these objects to variable names generated on the fly through exec() commands. I'm trying to make it print so that I see a list of the assigned names and not the memory addresses. Can anyone lend a hand?

EDIT: To clarify: Trying to make the objects assign to PatientXXXX variable names instead of the names themselves. For instance, the first person in the database would be assigned as Patient0001 = Person(John, Smith, johnsmith@gmail.com, False, False, False) and then print a list that's like [Patient0001, Patient0002] etc

Comment: @MarkMeyer sorry don't think I was clear in my question. Trying to make the objects assign to PatientXXXX variable names instead of the names themselves. For instance, the first person in the database would be assigned as Patient0001 = Person(John, Smith, johnsmith@gmail.com, False, False, False) and then print a list that's like [Patient0001, Patient0002] etc

Comment: "I'm assigning these objects to variable names generated on the fly through exec() commands." - don't. First, you should use a list or dict, not `exec`. Generating variable names through `exec` is undefined behavior inside a function, and a security risk even in cases where it works. Second, objects have no idea about what variables refer to them or what those variables are named.

Comment: Why don't you use a `dict` named `patient` and then map the id like `patient['0001'] = Person(...)`

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Gotcha, gonna restructure for a dict. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @SwetankPoddar restructuring for a dict now. Thanks for the input.